# Flutter_Webview support for windows

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I'm trying to open a website using flutter_webview on chrome windows os but it is showing the below error.

Tried url_launcher with the option forceWebView: true but it is opening the URL in a new tab which is not expected.
[image]

code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class MyWebView extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final String selectedUrl;

  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
      Completer<WebViewController>();

  MyWebView({
    @required this.title,
    @required this.selectedUrl,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: WebView(
          initialUrl: selectedUrl,
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
            _controller.complete(webViewController);
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter you can see that only Android and iOS are - as of May 2021 - supported.

Comment: Also found this related ticket: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37597